# Increasing the current to a solid-state relay?

Tags: current, relay, solid-state-relay

I've got two strings of LED Christmas lights that operate at 120 V / 0.04 A (4.8 W). I'd like to connect them to [this 5V solid-state relay](https://www.amazon.ca/SainSmart-8-Channel-Duemilanove-MEGA2560-MEGA1280/dp/B006J4G45G/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1417474888&sr=8-3&keywords=solid%20state%20relay):

[image]

Unfortunately, there's one small problem. According to the relay's datasheet:

> Load current: 0.1 to 2 AMP

The lights only draw 40 mA, much less than the minimum 100 mA listed on the datasheet. How can I work around this problem? Is there some sort of device or circuit I can connect that will cause the lights to draw more current (without damaging the lights)?

Comment: Does anyone know why there is a minimum current for a relay?  Something about cleaning the contacts?

Comment: That relay is discontinued according to Omron

Comment: @GeorgeHerold Solid-state relays are not relays.

Answer (score 1):

If you plug three strings of lights into each relay you'll have 120mA (assuming the lights actually draw 40mA each).

A 2K ohm 10W power resistor in parallel would also work.

It's also possible the lights will work just fine as is, at least for a hobby type application. The consequences of them not work (maybe the lights flickering instead of lighting steadily. or some lighting of the LEDs when the relay is 'off' due to the built-in snubber) are minor, so it may be worth a try.

Comment: Would it work to put a cap as load? (~ 1uF or so.. I didn't crunch the numbers.)  (You beat me to the resistor answer :^)

Comment: @GeorgeHerold Possibly, but a resistor in series would be necessary. More like 2uF, with maybe 100 ohms metal-oxide film resistor in series- and a bleeder in parallel of perhaps 470K.

Comment: Instead of a resistor, why not use a light bulb?

Comment: @jippie Sure, 7.5W-10W, but the light emission might interfere with whatever effect he's trying to achieve with the Xmas light. Heat needs to be considered with either a resistor or a light bulb.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany you hit the nail on the head. A lightbulb would have a side-effect: extra light emitted.

Comment: Does this look right? http://i.stack.imgur.com/Rovrz.png Also, just out of curiosity, why do you recommend a 10 W resistor? Won't the total power be 12 W?

Comment: @NathanOsman I'd start by moving the relay around. Switch at the LED's and coil at the Arduino side.

Comment: Oh... oops, that was a mistake.